# howto fire onCreateContextMenu or howto have a contextMenu without any View

Tags: android, contextmenu

I was wondering if it's possible to have a contextMenu without any view..?
Or any Dialog, acting simply like a contextMenu (a list of clickable items in fact)..?

I can explain: on the first use of the app, a pop-up (ContextMenu) list all option modes.
The actual trick is a button, registered for the ContextMenu and the firing is done by button.performLongClick()...

I don't want to have that button anymore, but I still want the ContextMenu

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,
jo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    static final int MY_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sets the activity layout
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout);

        showDialog(MY_DIALOG_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int dialogID) {
        Dialog d;
        switch(dialogID){
        case MY_DIALOG_ID:
            //CREATE YOUR DIALOG HERE
            break;
        }
        return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I'm not really satisfied, I wanted something more simple... I guess I will now learn how to build a nice Dialog :). Thanks!

Comment: you can build your dialog in the onCreate() method, just the way you were doing before. It will work. But the cleaner way to deal with dialog, as recommended by the SDK creators here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html
is this one...

Comment: I've follow your advice code, it does perfectly the trick! And I know now a bit more on Dialog. Thanks !